# Чи вірно побудовано речення?

Tags: правопис, граматика, семантика

Маю таке речення:
"В цій статті я поділюся з вами своїм досвідом зміни професії, та що підштовхнуло мене зробити цей крок."

Чи вірно воно побудовано? Які можливі зміни необхідні?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які не демонструють спроби автора самостійно відповісти на нього, змушують інших «вгадувати», чого саме хоче автор, і тому заважають надавати точні відповіді. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити запитання, натисніть edit у лівому нижньому куті під запитанням. Ще раз, ласкаво просимо і дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, що краще сказати так:

> В цій статті я поділюся з вами своїм досвідом зміни професії та тим,
>   що підштовхнуло мене зробити цей крок.

Ми кажемо зазвичай "ділитися чим?" - "тим, що..." або використовуємо іменнік ("ділитися досвідом"). Інший приклад:

> Чим ти з ним поділився? - ("*що* в мене було" - неправильно) Тим, що в мене було.

Comment: Додам (хоча це чисто інтуїтивно), що такі вказівні займенники часто опускають: «зроблю, що можу» («зроблю те, що можу»), «скажу, що знаю» («скажу те, що знаю») і т.ін. Але опускають їх частіше в тому випадку, коли дієслово перехідне, тобто вимагає знахідного відмінка: «зроблю (що?)», «скажу (що?)» і т.ін. Тут же дієслово неперехідне, вимагає орудного відмінка — «ділитися (чим?)». Тому «розповім те, що мене підштовхнуло» **і** «розповім, що мене підштовхнуло», але, здається, **лише** «поділюся тим, що мене підштовхнуло».

Comment: @Sasha саме так.